# Using __m256d registers

Tags: c++, x86, intel, simd, avx

How do you use `__m256d`?

Say I want to use the Intel AVX instruction [`_mm256_add_pd`](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/stdxe/2013/composerxe/compiler/cpp-mac/GUID-A37B748D-CDA4-42A6-8142-106CE1305BCE.htm) on a simple `Vector3` class with 3-64 bit `double` precision components (`x`, `y`, and `z`).  What is the correct way to use this?

Since `x`, `y` and `z` are *members* of the `Vector3` class, _can I declare them in `union` with an `__m256d` variable?

```
union Vector3
{
  struct { double x,y,z ; } ;
  __m256d _register ;  // the Intel register?
} ;
```

Then can I go:

```
Vector3 add( const Vector3& o )
{
  Vector3 result;
  result._register = _mm256_add_pd( _register, o._register ) ; // add 'em
  return result; 
}
```

Is that going to work?  Or do I need to declare temporaries,

```
Vector3 add( const Vector3& o )
{
  __m256d d1 = *(__m256d*)(&x) ; // ? Cast to __m256d?
  __m256d d2 = *(__m256d*)(&o.x) ; // ? Cast to __m256d?
  __m256d result = _mm256_add_pd( d1, d2 ) ; // add 'em
  return Vector3( result ) ; // make a ctor that accepts __m256d?
}
```

### Edit

I came up with this example,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <intrin.h>

int main()
{
  __m256d a, b, res;

  for( int i = 0; i < sizeof(__m256d)/sizeof(double); i++ )
  {
    a.m256d_f64[i] = i ;
    b.m256d_f64[i] = 2*i ;
  }

  // Perform __4__ adds.
  res = _mm256_add_pd(a, b);

  for( int i = 0; i < sizeof(__m256d)/sizeof(double); i++ )
  {
    printf("%f + %f = %f\n", a.m256d_f64[i], b.m256d_f64[i], res.m256d_f64[i]);
  }
  puts("");
}
```

I guess the question is now, *does* `_mm256_add_pd` do *load* operations *automatically*, or will something get messed up if I don't declare my `__m256d` registers as locals close to where they are used? (I'm afraid of a [hotel room / deskdrawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope/6445794#6445794) type problem)

### Edit 2:

I tried adding an `__m256` register to my rather large project, and I got a whole bunch of

> error C2719: 'value': formal parameter with __declspec(align('32')) won't be aligned

Errors, it leads me to believe that you *can't* keep `__m256` registers inside a class, instead they should be declared as locals?

Comment: Why only three doubles? The reference guide you linked to says each vector contains four doubles

Comment: Well, I don't need the 4th double, so I leave it unassigned,

Comment: What is the difference between `__m256d` and `__mm256d`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First I'd like to clear up a little confusion.  `__m256d` isn't a type of register, it's a data type that *can* be loaded into an AVX register.  A `__m256d` is no more a register than an `int` is a register.  There are a few ways to get data in and out of an `__m256d` (or any other vector type):

**Using a `union`:** Yes, the `union` trick works.  It works very well, since the union will generally have the correct alignment (although `malloc` might not, use `posix_memalign` or `_aligned_malloc`).

```
class Vector3 {
public:
    Vector3(double xx, double yy, double zz);
    Vector3(__m256d vvec);


    Vector3 operator+(const Vector3 &other) const
    {
        return Vector3(_mm256_add_pd(vec, other.vec));
    }

    union {
        struct {
            double x, y, z;
        };
        __m256d vec; // a data field, maybe a register, maybe not
    };
};
```

**Using intrinsics:** Inside a function, it's usually easier to use intrinsics to get data in and out of a vector type.

```
__m256d vec = ...;
double x, y, z;
vec = _mm256_add_pd(vec, _mm256_set_pd(x, y, z, 0.0));
```

**Using pointer casts:** Casting pointers is the last resort for a couple of reasons.

1. The pointer might not be aligned correctly.
2. Casting pointers can sometimes mess with the compiler's aliasing analysis.
3. Pointer casting bypasses a number of safety guarantees.

So I'd only use pointer casting to plow through a big array of data.

Comment: In the first piece of code, the union is nested in a class of the same name as the union. That's a mistake, right?

Comment: @jogojapan: Yep, that's a mistake.

Comment: __Are you sure__ this is reasonable?  I plugged a `__m256` member in my Vector class, but got a whole bunch of [C2719](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/373ak2y1(VS.80).aspx) errors.  It leads me to believe that you _must_ declare the `__m256` register as a local, load your data into it, and then perform the adds.  While I thought this would be unnecessary copy, it turns out I can't _keep `__m256` registers around_..

Comment: It seems that this is a flaw in the compiler you are using.  The error C2719 indicates that it can't align the data correctly -- which means that the compiler is not capable of propagating a larger alignment to composite types.  File a bug report with your compiler vendor, this works fine in other compilers.

Comment: @bobobobo: And I want to make sure you get this, it bears repeating.  The `__m256d` type is **NOT** a register type, it is a data type.  Just like `int`.  You can keep `int` around and you can keep `__m256d` around, compiler bugs notwithstanding.